# NFS Directories between 2 Servers

Tags: css-js-aggregation

I have 2 parallel Drupal Web Servers running (serving for one Drupal Instance together) and now i need to install NFS. My experience in multi Drupal Servers is, each Drupal Instance (Server) uses their own Aggregated JS + CSS files (storing in: `sites/default/files/js` and `sites/default/files/css` folders) which can NOT be used as common. (Files can not be the same for both Servers. They use their own ones.)

Based on these issues, my questions are:

- How NFS actually works between Multi Drupal Servers?
- Which `directories` will be/need to be shared between?
- What will happen to Aggregated Files?
- What will happen to Web User Uploads paths and files? (Need any configuration in Drupal?)

Can anyone share these knowledge/experience please?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent synchronization issues, you should mount the files directory as a shared folder over NFS between the drupal webservers, so that each Drupal instance has a symlink to the same file share

e.g:

`/var/www/drupal-site-mysite/sites/default/files -> /var/lib/sitedata/drupal-site-mysite/files`

where `/var/lib/sitedata/drupal-site-mysite/files` is a NFS mount/share.

Comment: Oh ok, i see something from your answer :D but not all yet. So what about Aggregated Files? How to "exclude" these? (These files can not be commonly used.)

Comment: Aggregated files should be stored in the shared files folder